# Finding K smallest integers in an unsorted array of size N

Tags: c++

I am having a problem with a program:
Write a **C++ program** to find K smallest integers from an array of N given integers.
For example, if N=5, K=2, and the array is 7, 5, -1, 4, 2
The program should output -1, 2. 
**NO other array** can be used.
**NO sorting** can be used. 
The values of array elements **cannot be changed**.
I've tried for a long time and am stuck.
Any ideas will be of great help.
Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no attempt/effort/research shown.

Comment: Please...just a little hint will be useful!

Comment: @user2306890 Start by coding.

Comment: Can you use a binary tree? :-)

Comment: homework !!! This is not what we are doing here, you should study some programming materials. Stack overflow dedicated to enlarge your knowledge not doing your homeworks !!!!

Comment: Thanks everybody!! I've got the solution :) Hooray!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 variables, namely `small` and `smallest`.

1. Iterate over each element of the given array.
2. Compare the element against `small`.
3. If it's smaller than `small`, compare it to `smallest`.
4. If it's smaller than `smallest`, assign the value of `smallest` to `small`, and the element to `smallest`.
5. Otherwise, assign the element to `small`.

You still have to figure out how to initialise `small` and `smallest` in order to make the comparisons work as expected. Hint: limits!

Of course, this does not work for K > 2. If you don't know K beforehand, you'll need a container to store the results, and compare the elements against them. If you cannot use an extra container, good luck with that!